# onclick action on button works for only one condition

Tags: javascript, button, onclick

I am writing a php application with javascript and customized button. The problem is when the button is clicked, irrespective of clicking yes or cancel, it is doing a default function of clicking a 'yes'. Could you please help me in finding the error.

The php code is

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="javascript/access1.js"></script>
<form name="form_delete" id="form_delete" action="" method="POST" class="access">
|
|
|
<input type="hidden" name="deleteinstanceaction" value="1" />
</form>
<a id="_delete_btt" class="button" onClick="confirmDelete()">Delete</a>
<img class="ajaxload" style="display:none;" id="ajaxld" src="images/ajax-loader.gif"/>
```

**Edit1**
The javascript code is

```
function confirmDelete() {
var agree=confirm("Are you sure you wish to continue? This will remove the selected item permamently!");
if (agree)
return true ;
else
return false ;
}
```

Can the problem be related to AJAX?
if I use normal button then this javascript works fine for e.g. in the below case this works fine on both 'yes' and 'no' click

```
<input type="submit" name="delete_state" value="Delete selected state" onClick="confirmDelete()">
```

**Edit2**
The code in the .js file is :

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
Access.initEventHandlers(); });

   var Access = {
   initEventHandlers : function(){
    if($('#_delete_btt')){
        $("#_delete_btt").click(function(e){
            Access.processSubmit();
        });
    }
    processSubmit: function (event) {
        $('#_delete_btt').hide();   
        $('#ajaxld').show();
        setTimeout("Access.formsub()",500);
    },
    formsub: function () {
        var url = 'php/corecontroller.php?ts='+new Date().getTime();
        $.post(url, $('#form_delete').serialize(), Access.oncomplete,"json");
    },
    oncecomplete:function(data,textStatus){
        if(textStatus == "success"){
                if(data.result == "1"){
                    //sucessful
                    $('#ajaxld').hide();
                    htmlstr += "Deleted";
                }
                            }
                    }
             }
```

Could you please suggest how to proceed further?

Comment: Perhaps you show more of your codes (JavaScript)

Comment: You need to show us the javascript function `confirmDelete`

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a click handler attached to the link by chance? Normally, returning false would indeed cancel the navigation.. but I don't think it cancels a click handler when attached like that.

So, if you did something like..

```
$("#_delete_btt").click(submitTheForm);
```

or

```
document.getElementById('_delete_btt').onclick(submitTheForm)
```

at a previous point, that will probably still submit the form as it isn't listening for a 'can I continue' from another bound callback. Assuming this is the case, bind a function to the 'a' tag that will confirm, and then process based on the user's response.

Edit:

Based on the new code you posted, we just need to change the program flow. Either put the confirmation in the click callback:

```
    $("#_delete_btt").click(function(e){
        if(confirmDelete()){
            Access.processSubmit();
        }
    });
```

or put the code to process the submit in the confirmDelete:

```
function confirmDelete() {
    var agree=confirm("Are you sure you wish to continue? This will remove the selected item permamently!");
    if (agree){
        Access.processSubmit();
        return true ;
    } else {
        return false ;
    }
}
```

Either way, what I had suspected was happening is in fact happening. The click event fires regardless of whether or not a callback returns false, causing the processSubmit to fire off as well.

Comment: I posted the .js code in Edit2 of my question. Could you please have a look at it and suggest me where I should add the piece of code you mentioned?

Comment: Based on what you updated with, that processSubmit has to be bound somewhere. If you can find where it is being bound or called, that would help a great deal... at that point I'd suggest just removing that line and calling the processSubmit from the confirmDelete.

Comment: I partly understand what you said. I also added more code to the javascript section for you to better understand. Any further thoughts?

Comment: What is in the initEventHandlers method? I'm betting that the missing piece is in there.

Comment: oops i forgot to add function name, now its there. kindly have a look.

Comment: Great. Unfortunately still same behaviour but I get your idea. I think we are very near. Access.js and javascript code are in separate files, can they still access each other's functions?

Comment: Absolutely. When you load javascript files, their methods get pumped into a 'global' space. So, which style did you end up going with? If you chose the last one, did you remove the $('#_delete_btt').click(......) from the initEventHandlers?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, returning `false` in Javascript does not prevent a link to be followed if there is a `href` attribute defined.

Since that's not your case I would define a `href` attribute set to `#`:

```
<a href="#" id="_delete_btt" class="button" onClick="confirmDelete()">Delete</a>
```